# Parametrizing intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm working on a question that require parametrizing some curves:

> C is the curve of intersection of the hyperbolic paraboloid $z = y^2 − x^2$ and the cylinder 
>   $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above. Let $x$ and $y$ be in terms of $t$ where $0 ≤ t ≤ 2π$.

I thought it was quite obvious that the parametrization is $\cos{t}, \sin{t}, \sin^2{t} - \cos^2{t}$, but no, apparently it's wrong:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you saying it is wrong? Do you have a reason to believe that another answer is true?

Comment: I don't see how it's wrong. Is it disagreeing with an answer you have?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval - It's graded by an online computer grader on those homework sites and it says that is not the correct answer.

Comment: Well, I don't know this grader, but I think your parametrization is correct.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval - Hm, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Try entering the answer $\bigl(\sin t, \cos t, -\cos 2t \bigr)$. This answer is equivalent to yours, but maybe the computer system is too dumb to realize this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it's 3 years too late to change it now :)

Comment: What about now? :)